# How to adjust dialog layout when soft keyboard appears using the latest WindowInset API

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-bottomsheetdialog, windowinsets

### Question:

How to use the **latest WindowInset API** to adjust space betweeen my dialog and softkeyboard?

---

I have a BottomSheetDialog with some EditText. The default animation will show the soft keyboard right below my EditText which will cover my save button. After doing some research, I added this line into my `BottomSheetDialog` fragment

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

And it worked (as the picture is shown down below)!

[This is what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9IUu.png)

But apparently `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` is deprecated.

```
   * @deprecated Call {@link Window#setDecorFitsSystemWindows(boolean)} with {@code false} and
   * install an {@link OnApplyWindowInsetsListener} on your root content view that fits insets
   * of type {@link Type#ime()}.
```

And I couldn't figure out how to use the new `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` to achieve the same effect.
Here is my current `BottomSheetDialog` fragment:

```
public class BottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//      Adding this line works, but it's deprecated in API 30
//      getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
      
        getDialog().getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_dialog_cash, container, false);
        view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v, insets) -> {
            Log.d("dialog", "onCreateView: ");
            Insets imeInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime());
            v.setPadding(0,0,0,imeInsets.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        return view;
    }
```

I use an onclicklistener in another fragment to show this dialog. Code in `Another fragment`

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog();
        dialog.show(getParentFragmentManager(), "BottomSheetDialog");
    }
```

In fact, the log indicates that the listener is never triggered when the soft keyboard pop up.
FYI, I'm following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acC7SR1EXsI&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers) and [this blog](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/android11-windowinsets-part1).

Answer (score 13):

After more research, I find out that if I use `viewBinding` and replace `view` with `bind.getRoot()`, then everything works fine. I'm not sure why (maybe I should use in `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView` ?) but the code should be helpful for people having the same issue.

```
// NOTE: you have to set this in the activity instead of fragment.
getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);

// Only work with API30 or above!
bind.getRoot().setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v, insets) -> { 
    imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.ime()).bottom;
    bind.getRoot().setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight);
    return insets;
});
```

One thing to be noticed is that setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false) means the app (you) are responsible for all the system windows includes the status bar and navigation bar.

I also find the tutorials linked down below are very useful, please check if you wanna know more about windowInsets and new animation callback.

[New WindowInsets APIs for checking the keyboard (IME) visibility and size](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d)

[Window Insets and Keyboard Animations Tutorial for Android 11](https://www.raywenderlich.com/18393648-window-insets-and-keyboard-animations-tutorial-for-android-11)

Answer (score 11):

Compat Version

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(rootView()) { _, insets ->
    val imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
    rootView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, imeHeight)
    insets
}
```

Or use [Insetter library](https://chrisbanes.github.io/insetter/)

```
 WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
 rootView().applyInsetter {
        type(ime = true) {
            padding()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that seemed to do the trick for me was setting the style of the BottomSheetDialog to use the following:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateVisible</item>
</style>
```